# Are question about simulation on topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/339/historically-accurate-ww2-simulation) or type of question acceptable or not?  Why?

As a side note, would asking about the historical accuracy of a game be on topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was one of the ones who voted to close this one. The reasons for this aren't entirely obvious to me, so I can understand why you asked the question. A few gut reactions to this:

- There are [other places](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) on the Internet to ask this question and you will probably get a pretty good answer elsewhere.
- I feel like there might be a risk that less 'serious' history questions might discourage professional historians to contribute.
- There aren't going to be many questions like this, so we are not losing a great deal by closing them.
- The answers are probably going to be pretty subjective.

All that said, you should definitely check out [Combat Mission - Battle for Normandy](http://www.battlefront.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=blogcategory&id=273&Itemid=456), it is awesome ;).

Comment: +1 I agree with these reasons...

Answer (score 1):

Reenactments should also be considered off-topic imho.